# JSF ExceptionHandler - Response already committed in some cases

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, jsf-2.2

We have implemented a custom ExceptionHandler that attempts to intercept any `NonexistentConversationException` that are thrown if a user requests a URL with an old cid in it (eg. bookmarked link etc.).
The handler simply removed the cid from the URL and performs a redirect to the updated URL.

This solution seems to work in most cases, we have a number of different user 'roles' within the App each with their own login areas and for one of these user types it seems that `fc.getExternalContext().isResponseCommitted()` is always true when the ExceptionHandler fires which means we are unable to perform the redirect. All other user types it works ok.

I am not sure exactly what the difference is with this user type for this to happen, I am guessing some CDI bean we using setup differently

Is there a way to unsure the ExceptionHandler kicks in earlier before the response is committed?

Below is the handler...

```
public class ConversationExpiredExceptionHandler
        extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConversationExpiredExceptionHandler.class);
    
    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;
    
    private static String CONVERSATION_PARAM = "cid";
    
    public ConversationExpiredExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {

        for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i =
                getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
                i.hasNext();) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
            Throwable t = context.getException();

            if (t instanceof javax.enterprise.context.NonexistentConversationException 
                || t instanceof org.jboss.weld.contexts.NonexistentConversationException
                || t.getCause() instanceof org.jboss.weld.contexts.NonexistentConversationException /* can be wrapped in FacesException */) {

                final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                
                try {
                    if (!fc.getExternalContext().isResponseCommitted()) {
                        if(Faces.getRequestQueryStringMap().containsKey(CONVERSATION_PARAM)) {
                            String requestedUrl = Faces.getRequestURLWithQueryString();
                            String updatedUrl = this.removeQueryParameter(requestedUrl,CONVERSATION_PARAM);
                            log.debug("No conversation active for {}, redirecting to {}",requestedUrl,updatedUrl);
                            fc.getExternalContext().redirect(updatedUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    fc.renderResponse();
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new FacesException(ex);
                } finally {
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        getWrapped().handle();
    }
    
    private String removeQueryParameter(String url, String parameterName) throws URISyntaxException {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
        List<NameValuePair> queryParameters = uriBuilder.getQueryParams();
        for (Iterator<NameValuePair> queryParameterItr = queryParameters.iterator(); queryParameterItr.hasNext();) {
            NameValuePair queryParameter = queryParameterItr.next();
            if (queryParameter.getName().equals(parameterName)) {
                queryParameterItr.remove();
            }
        }
        uriBuilder.setParameters(queryParameters);
        return uriBuilder.build().toString();
    }
```

Comment: The response committed exception occurs after the headers have been written and the body has been started, then an attempt at writing another header is done (I believe (not 100% sure)). You could get ahold of the request output stream with the debugger and see whats been done in this particular case. I know this isn't a satisfactory answer, but that's how I would go about solving it.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanS.Fisher I will try this when I get a bit more time to look at it